# Npgsql - Problema com Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Estou encontrando problemas para utilizar o PostgreSQL juntamento com o Entity Framework 6.

Ao tentar buscar os dados do meu repositório recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Versão dos softwares envolvidos:

- Versão do dot.NET: 4.5
- Versão do PostgreSQL: 9.5.0
- Versão do Entity: 6.1.3
- Providers: EntityFramework6.Npgsql "3.0.5" e Npgsql "3.0.5"

**Minha classe de contexto:**

```
namespace Teste.Infra.Data.Contexto
{
    public class TesteContexto : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PerfilAcesso> PerfisAcesso { get; set; }

        public TesteContexto () : base("name=DB_Teste")
        {
            var instancia = Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance;
        }

        protected override sealed void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.Database.Initialize(false);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            ConfigurarMapeamento(modelBuilder);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected virtual void Inicializar()
        {
        }

        protected virtual void ConfigurarMapeamento(DbModelBuilder modelo)
        {
            modelo.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioMapeamento());
            modelo.Configurations.Add(new PerfilAcessoMapeamento());
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe de Mapeamento:**

```
public class UsuarioMapeamento : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMapeamento()
    {
        ToTable("TB_USUARIOS", "public");
        HasKey(d => d.UsuarioID);

        Property(d => d.Nome).HasColumnName("FL_NOME").HasColumnType("varchar").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        HasRequired(d => d.PerfilAcesso).WithMany().Map(e => e.MapKey("FL_PERFILACESSOID"));
    }
}
```

**Classe base:**

```
public class Usuario
    {
        public short UsuarioID { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string UsuarioAcesso { get; set; }

        public string SenhaAcesso { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public short Situacao { get; set; }

        public virtual PerfilAcesso PerfilAcesso { get; set; }
    }
```

**Vale ressaltar que estou utilizando um repositório genérico. Segue classe:**

```
public class RepositorioBase<T> : IDisposable, IRepositorioBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected IgrejaNETContexto Contexto = new TesteContexto ();

    public virtual void Adicionar(T item)
    {
        Contexto.Set<T>().Add(item);
        Contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Remover(T item)
    {
        Contexto.Set<T>().Remove(item);
        Contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Editar(T item)
    {
        Contexto.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual T ObtemPorId(object id)
    {
        return Contexto.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Filtrar(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {

        return Todos().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Todos()
    {
        return Contexto.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> TodosNoTracking()
    {
        try
        {
            return Contexto.Set<T>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Contexto.Dispose();
    }
```

**Como estou tentando utilizar os dados:**

```
        UsuarioRepositorio rep = new UsuarioRepositorio();
        var dados = rep.Todos();
        foreach (var item in dados)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.UsuarioID + " - " + item.Nome);
        }
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o `app.config` na pergunta?

Comment: Coloca o app.config.